# Twitter - get number of shares using the new API

Tags: twitter

So since we no longer can get share counts using Twitter's API anymore, are there any workarounds to get the result, no matter how convoluted?

The only thing I'm thinking of is using the `search/tweets` endpoint to get tweets page by page and then using the `next_results` object to get the next page, counting each time.

Obviously this has massive flaws, for a popular search term the next iteration of the loop will probably have duplicates, not to mention too many API calls will invoke the rate limiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no good way to do it from the API.  There are third party services which track shares.

I use http://newsharecounts.com/ - once you've signed up your domain, you can call a URL like:

```
http://public.newsharecounts.com/count.json?url=https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/03/this-is-what-a-graph-of-8000-fake-twitter-accounts-looks-like/
```

And get back a JSON count

```
{
  "url":"https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/03/this-is-what-a-graph-of-8000-fake-twitter-accounts-looks-like/",
  "count":739,
  "tracked":6,
  "historic":733
}
```

There's also http://opensharecount.com/ which works in a similar way - although I've not had much success with it.